# I want to update the document in collection in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Here is 1 documents in which memberArray is column having multiple challeng_video array of object
I want to update status in challenges_video of memberArraay corresponding to the date what i can do

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b0b13d2339979e7c4d5c8"),
    "cid" : "1601899180793",
    "sb_cid" : "1601899180809",
    "Date" : ISODate("2020-10-05T11:01:23.000+05:30"),
    "created_at" : "2020-10-05 05:31:23",
    "teampoints" : 0,
    "status" : 0,
    "membersArray" : [
        {
            "uid" : "1601354624686",
            "cid" : "1601899180793",
            "total" : 0,
            "challenge_video" : [
                {
                    "status" : 1,
                    "date" : "2019-01-05",
                    "videoUrl" : ""
                },
                {
                    "status" : 0,
                    "date" : "2019-01-05",
                    "videoUrl" : ""
                }
            ],
            "captain" : 0
        }
    ],
    "teamName" : "Team crrew",
    "teamid" : "1601899283837",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/

Comment: what language/framework are you looking for? you need to specify more details.

Comment: @raga i am worked on node with mongoDB

Comment: read these article  https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/updateOne   https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_update.asp

Comment: it will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is works for me let me know if it works for you

```
db.members.updateMany({'cid': item.cid},
{ '$set':
{ 'membersArray.$[].challenge_video.$[ele].status' : 3}},
{arrayFilters: [{'ele.date': "2020-10-05",'ele.status':0}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> db.members.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b0b13d2339979e7c4d5c8"),
        "cid" : "1601899180793",
        "sb_cid" : "1601899180809",
        "Date" : ISODate("2020-10-05T05:31:23Z"),
        "created_at" : "2020-10-05 05:31:23",
        "teampoints" : 0,
        "status" : 0,
        "membersArray" : [
                {
                        "uid" : "1601354624686",
                        "cid" : "1601899180793",
                        "total" : 0,
                        "challenge_video" : [
                                {
                                        "status" : 1,
                                        "date" : "2019-01-05",
                                        "videoUrl" : ""
                                },
                                {
                                        "status" : 0,
                                        "date" : "2019-01-05",
                                        "videoUrl" : ""
                                }
                        ],
                        "captain" : 0
                }
        ],
        "teamName" : "Team crrew",
        "teamid" : "1601899283837",
        "__v" : 0
}
> db.members.aggregate([
... {$unwind:"$membersArray"},
... {$unwind:"$membersArray.challenge_video"},
... {$match:{"membersArray.challenge_video.date":"2019-01-05"}},
... {$project:{_id:1,"membersArray.challenge_video.status":1}}
... ]).forEach(function(doc){
...     var vstatus = doc.membersArray.challenge_video.status;
...     print("doc id:", doc._id);
...     print("status:", vstatus);
...     db.members.updateMany(
...      {"_id": doc._id},
...      {$set:{"membersArray.$[].challenge_video.$[].status":"99"}},
...      {upsert:true}
... );
...  });
doc id: ObjectId("5f7b0b13d2339979e7c4d5c8")
status: 1
doc id: ObjectId("5f7b0b13d2339979e7c4d5c8")
status: 0
>
> db.members.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b0b13d2339979e7c4d5c8"),
        "cid" : "1601899180793",
        "sb_cid" : "1601899180809",
        "Date" : ISODate("2020-10-05T05:31:23Z"),
        "created_at" : "2020-10-05 05:31:23",
        "teampoints" : 0,
        "status" : 0,
        "membersArray" : [
                {
                        "uid" : "1601354624686",
                        "cid" : "1601899180793",
                        "total" : 0,
                        "challenge_video" : [
                                {
                                        "status" : "99",
                                        "date" : "2019-01-05",
                                        "videoUrl" : ""
                                },
                                {
                                        "status" : "99",
                                        "date" : "2019-01-05",
                                        "videoUrl" : ""
                                }
                        ],
                        "captain" : 0
                }
        ],
        "teamName" : "Team crrew",
        "teamid" : "1601899283837",
        "__v" : 0
}
> print("MongoDB",db.version());
MongoDB 4.4.1
>
```

Try this if you want to update to specific array element(using array filters)

```
> db.members.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b0b13d2339979e7c4d5c8"),
        "cid" : "1601899180793",
        "sb_cid" : "1601899180809",
        "Date" : ISODate("2020-10-05T05:31:23Z"),
        "created_at" : "2020-10-05 05:31:23",
        "teampoints" : 0,
        "status" : 0,
        "membersArray" : [
                {
                        "uid" : "1601354624686",
                        "cid" : "1601899180793",
                        "total" : 0,
                        "challenge_video" : [
                                {
                                        "status" : 1,
                                        "date" : "2019-01-05",
                                        "videoUrl" : ""
                                },
                                {
                                        "status" : 0,
                                        "date" : "2019-01-05",
                                        "videoUrl" : ""
                                }
                        ],
                        "captain" : 0
                }
        ],
        "teamName" : "Team crrew",
        "teamid" : "1601899283837",
        "__v" : 0
}
> db.members.aggregate([
... {$unwind:"$membersArray"},
... {$unwind:"$membersArray.challenge_video"},
... {$match:{"membersArray.challenge_video.date":"2019-01-05",
...          "membersArray.challenge_video.status":1}
...      },
... {$project:{_id:1,
...            "membersArray.challenge_video.date":1,
...            "membersArray.challenge_video.status":1}
... }
... ]).forEach(function(doc){
...     var vstatus = doc.membersArray.challenge_video.status;
...     print("doc id:", doc._id);
...     print("status:", vstatus);
...       db.members.updateOne(
...        {"_id":doc._id},
...        {$set:{"membersArray.$[].challenge_video.$[elem2].status":"99"}},
...        {arrayFilters:[{"elem2.status":1}]}
... );
...  });
doc id: ObjectId("5f7b0b13d2339979e7c4d5c8")
status: 1
>
> db.members.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f7b0b13d2339979e7c4d5c8"),
        "cid" : "1601899180793",
        "sb_cid" : "1601899180809",
        "Date" : ISODate("2020-10-05T05:31:23Z"),
        "created_at" : "2020-10-05 05:31:23",
        "teampoints" : 0,
        "status" : 0,
        "membersArray" : [
                {
                        "uid" : "1601354624686",
                        "cid" : "1601899180793",
                        "total" : 0,
                        "challenge_video" : [
                                {
                                        "status" : "99",
                                        "date" : "2019-01-05",
                                        "videoUrl" : ""
                                },
                                {
                                        "status" : 0,
                                        "date" : "2019-01-05",
                                        "videoUrl" : ""
                                }
                        ],
                        "captain" : 0
                }
        ],
        "teamName" : "Team crrew",
        "teamid" : "1601899283837",
        "__v" : 0
}
>
```

Comment: Hi,it acutually updated whole status, but i want to update the status which date i give in match condition

Comment: check-in "challenge_video" you have a similar document with no difference, hence it updates two records. If you have any identifier to identify the status fields as unique, let me know. we can add that in match query.

Comment: yes if i have two different date then how can we do

Comment: and i have status 3 i have to update by 2 how can i

Comment: "message": "No array filter found for identifier 'c' in path 'membersArray.$[].challenge_video.$[c].status
```````````
now it says

Comment: please check my answer section above. I have updated it.

Comment: check i have given answer below